# Caching entity methods/properties in symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, entities

Im wondering what the best practice for caching entity / values is in symfony2?

For example if i have a entity $entity, with a method ->getLongCalculation(), i want to store that result rather than have to work it out every time its called.

Obviously its very easy just to store the result in APC using the entity ID but the problem i have is that that has to be done outside of the entity, as it doesnt have access to the container.

So for example i end up with code repeated everywhere in my controllers where i call the getter, checking if we already know the value.

Is there any clean way for me to just be able to call $entity->getLongCalculation() and the function itself handle any caching? Obviously i can just pass the container into the entity but i understand thats not best practice?

Whats the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it acceptable for you to store in database the result of longCalculation ?

In this case ( i used it for my needs ) you can use lifeCycle events ( prePersist & preUpdate) to populate your result in entity

- http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,

Yes, saving the results of calculations in database - in the same table or as a relation, it doesn't matter. It's better than cache, because it changes only when the entity is changing. Then you can use Doctrine cache system - it's quite simple and needs only to set the cache method on the repository or query (setResultCacheMethod or sth like that).

You can achieve the best performance with Doctrine cache (sql and results), redis for session, proper database architecture which avoids long time calculations and Varnish with ESI (reverse proxy cache).

At the and of the work you can finish with application at least 1000% faster than in the beginning.

Regards,